# WPF поместить содержимое ToolTip в StackPanel

Tags: wpf

У меня есть TextBox, который реагирует на ошибки валидации (текст ошибки показывается в при наведении на треугольник). Помимо текста ошибки, я хочу в ToolTip добавить еще один текст блок, но когда это делаю, текст ошибки перестает отображаться.

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ExpenseTracker.Views.ValidationTextBox"
         x:Name="userControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:validationRules="clr-namespace:ExpenseTracker.ValidationRules"
         xmlns:views="clr-namespace:ExpenseTracker.Views">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ErrorTemplate" 
                     TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
        <Grid>
            <Border 
                BorderBrush="Red" 
                BorderThickness="1">
            </Border>
            <Polygon 
                Fill="Red" 
                Points="0,0 10,0 10,10" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=adorner, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
            </Polygon>
            <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="adorner"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ErrorTemplate}"/>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Width="200">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="Input" 
                     Mode="TwoWay" 
                     x:Name="textBox" 
                     NotifyOnValidationError="True" 
                     UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <validationRules:NotEmptyRule/>
                </Binding.ValidationRules >
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

После модификации:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ExpenseTracker.Views.ValidationTextBox"
         x:Name="userControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:validationRules="clr-namespace:ExpenseTracker.ValidationRules"
         xmlns:views="clr-namespace:ExpenseTracker.Views">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ErrorTemplate" 
                     TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
        <Grid>
            <Border 
                BorderBrush="Red" 
                BorderThickness="1">
            </Border>
            <Polygon 
                Fill="Red" 
                Points="0,0 10,0 10,10" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Polygon.ToolTip>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=adorner, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Polygon.ToolTip>
            </Polygon>
            <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="adorner"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ErrorTemplate}"/>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Width="200">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="Input" 
                     Mode="TwoWay" 
                     x:Name="textBox" 
                     NotifyOnValidationError="True" 
                     UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <validationRules:NotEmptyRule/>
                </Binding.ValidationRules >
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: А зачем вам StackPanel внутри ToolTip?

Comment: Я хочу добавить еще текст, например имя элемента у которого возникла обибка. Например, "Full name" + "Can't be empty" , "Password" + "Can't be empty" .

Comment: Вы можете использовать класс Run внутри TextBlock для этого, элементы по умолчанию будут в одну строку

Comment: Я нему понять в чем проблема, если устанавливаю только один TextBlock, текс ошибки все равно не устанавливается:                                                                    
       <Polygon.ToolTip>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=adorner, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"></TextBlock>
                    </Polygon.ToolTip>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начну с "претензий". Пожалуйста, научитесь приводить ***минимальный*** самодостаточный пример, такой, чтобы любой желающий ответить мог скопировать код в студию, быстренько запустить и увидеть вашу проблему. Но, с другой стороны, код не должен содержать ничего лишнего, отвлекающего внимание и засоряющего вопрос.

---

По сути ваш вопрос можно переписать примерно так:

Почему здесь привязка работает нормально и всплывающая подсказка отображается:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Name="TextBlock1" Text="111"/>
    <TextBlock Text="222" ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=TextBlock1, Path=Text}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

А здесь не работает, отображается пустое место:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Name="TextBlock1" Text="111"/>
    <TextBlock Text="222">
        <TextBlock.ToolTip>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=TextBlock1, Path=Text}"/>
        </TextBlock.ToolTip>
    </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

---

Ответ на вопрос: дело в том, что фича `ElementName` ищет имя только внутри визуального дерева элементов, а `ToolTip` лежит вне этого дерева (в отдельном дереве?) и если в первом варианте поиск начинается внутри дерева (с текстблока 222), то во втором поиск выполняется в отдельном дереве, в котором, элемент с именем `TextBlock1`, конечно, отсутствует.

Решение — воспользоваться фичей `Source={x:Reference ...}`, которая ищет по всей  разметке XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Name="TextBlock1" Text="111"/>
    <TextBlock Text="222">
        <TextBlock.ToolTip>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference TextBlock1}, Path=Text}"/>
        </TextBlock.ToolTip>
    </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как насчёт того, чтобы перенести тултип из ресурсов в сам элемент?

```
        <TextBox Width="200"
                 ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self} , Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
```

Это не решение с шаблоном, но оно работает. Чтобы решить проблему через шаблоны, используйте [Inspect](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winauto/inspect-objects) для того чтобы осмотреть построенное дерево и изменить привязку данных в шаблоне.